# Prevent to view some of code files on TFS

Tags: tfs

I have a project on TFS that contains a class library and a website. I want to prevent some of my users to view the content of that class library , but can use the result of class library( the DLL file that created after build). Is there anybody there that can help me about this ?!

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to go into the security settings of your source control if i'm not wrong. To do this open your `Source Control Explorer` in Visual Studio, right click the class library project, click `Security...` and research the options there.